# WordPress auto embed of YouTube videos - adding filter to handle `end` attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, video, youtube, embed

WordPress automatically converts a YouTube URL in the content of a page/post to a embedded iframe video.

It respects the `start` parameter, if present, in the YouTube URL, but it does not respect the `end` parameter, if present.

I therefore need to locate the WordPress code that handles this automatic YouTube embed functionality so I can, hopefully, hook in my own filter that ([using this solution](http://nimrodflores.com/internet-marketing/video-marketing/how-to-embed-youtube-videos-with-specific-start-and-end-times/)) will take care of the `end` requirements.

I have searched through the `class-wp-embed.php`, `class-oembed.php` and `media.php` files of the `/wp-includes/` directory and, in the latter, thought I had found the code I needed...

`apply_filters( 'wp_embed_handler_youtube', $embed, $attr, $url, $rawattr )`

...but that filter doesn't seem to get called.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6):

I had same problems and not found answer. So here is working solution:

```
add_filter('embed_oembed_html', 'my_theme_embed_handler_oembed_youtube', 10, 4);
function my_theme_embed_handler_oembed_youtube($html, $url, $attr, $post_ID) {
    if (strpos($url, 'youtube.com')!==false) {
        /*  YOU CAN CHANGE RESULT HTML CODE HERE */
        $html = '<div class="youtube-wrap">'.$html.'</div>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the youtube url and set various condition.I have implemented it in past.You may get some reference from the below code:

```
 if(strpos($url, "youtube")!==false)
  {
    if(strpos($url, "<object")===false)
    {
     if(strpos($url, "<iframe")===false)
     {
      if(strpos($url, "//youtu.be/")===false)
      {
       $url_string = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
       parse_str($url_string, $args);
       $videoId = isset($args['v']) ? $args['v'] : false;

      }
      else
      {
       $url_string = explode('/',$url);
       $videoId = $url_string[3];
      }
     }
     else
     {
      $pattern = '!//(?:www.)?youtube.com/embed/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)!i';
      $result = preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);   

      $videoId = $matches[1];         
     }
    }
    else
    {
      preg_match('#<object[^>]+>.+?http://www.youtube.com/v/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+).+?</object>#s', $url, $matches);
      $videoId = $matches[1];
    }
    $urlfrom = 'youtube';
    $video_thumb= '';

}
```